# Open Graph video from my home site server not playing on facebook

Tags: video-streaming, facebook-opengraph

**1)    Open Graph video from my home site server not playing on facebook**

I do not get Open Graph video from my site www.thetruthagreement.com to work on Facebook.

When I swap one line of code with code from files2.flippish.com - it works perfectly in Safari, Chrome and Firefox:

[WORKING WELL - all on files2.flippish.com]

`<meta property="og:video" content="http://files2.flippish.com/files/videos/player.swf?file=http://files2.flippish.com/files/videos/Happyendings/HE Nicole Anne Reyes final.mp4&autostart=true">`

I copied the exact same video file to my site and change this one line of code to reference my jwplayer and this same video on my server.  Every thing else is the same, but the video does not start playing:

[NOT WORKING - all on thetruthagreement.com]

`<meta property="og:video" content="http://www.thetruthagreement.com/jwplayer/player.swf?file=http://www.thetruthagreement.com/video/HE Nicole Anne Reyes final.mp4&autostart=true" />`

No errors using Object Debugger.

The (latest) flash player goes blank in the same three browsers, with no error message.  I can “fool” Safari to work though, by enabling “ClickToFlash” and manually click in the player window to get the video started.

Both servers were without SSL and SSL was turned off on facebook and the browsers.  My web host maddogdomains.com says it must be facebook’s fault… ?

I have now changed my site to SSL, but that did not change anything.

**2)    Possible to force immediate refreshing of objects?**
Your Object Debugger is great for testing for errors, but I am stuck in the process of testing why this does not work, as it takes many hours before the object is updated at facebook.  Is there a way to refresh immediately?

**3)    Possible to delete objects?**
After I added SSL to my petition site, I have now two objects to like.  I want to please know how to delete the old one, not using SSL?

Answer (score 0):

[Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) will clear the cache for an object URL as well as showing which meta tags were detected and if any of them are incorrect. There's also an API endpoint to trigger a re-scrape of your objects - see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/defining-an-object/#update for details

There's no reason to 'delete' an object, just don't publish actions against objects you don't want or need anymore, i think if the object URL stops responding (or starts returning an error) the existing actions posted against that object are still accessible, but users clicking the links will be brought to you (now error) page

Comment: Thank you very much for responding, Igy!

I read the Debug Tool is supposed to  re-scrape, but the second day I could not update the site with Debug Tool.  Don't know  if it was me…

Not that I get it to work again I found the following:
1) WORKS:       JWPLAYER on files2.flippish.com   > FILE on files2.flippish.com
2) NOT WORKING: JWPLAYER on thetruthagreement.com > FILE on thetruthagreement.com
3) WORKS:       JWPLAYER on files2.flippish.com   > FILE on thetruthagreement.com
4) NOT WORKING: JWPLAYER on thetruthagreement.com > FILE on files2.flippish.com

Comment: Seems like the problem is getting the JWPLAYER on my site to work.  Maybe some permission on the server - as it is working when I call it manually by clicking inside Flash Player in Safari (when using “ClickToFlash”)?

I will ask longtailvideo if there is some code to use to make sure facebook is calling up the jwplayer automatically. 

S:)

Comment: It works with V5, but not V6 yet... is what longtailvideo.com told me.
They will implement it.
:)